# Mpi4py scatter, gather and send-recv

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to communicate between processes as in below code, such that every processor has two data dictionaries viz. "data" & "dataPrev". dataPrev is the dictionary from the previous ranked processor

```
    from Mpi4py import MPI

    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    data = {'a': 11, 'b': b, 'c': c}
    comm.barrier()
    if rank == size-1: # last rank
            reqSend = comm.isend(data, dest=0, tag=rank)
            reqSend.wait()
    else:
            reqSend = comm.isend(data, dest=rank+1, tag=rank)
            reqSend.wait()

    if rank == 0:
            reqRecv = comm.irecv(source=size-1, tag=rank)
            dataPrev = reqRecv.wait()
    else:
            reqRecv = comm.irecv(source=rank-1, tag=rank)
            dataPrev = reqRecv.wait()
    comm.barrier()
```

Once that sent and recv has happened, I am making some changes to the values stored in dataPrev keys. This step is done.

Then, I'm gathering all the dictionaries from all the processors onto root = 0: if there are P processors, then in total I have 2P dictionaries.

```
    senddata=[]
    for j in range(3):  # 3 keys in the data
          senddata.append([1, data[j]])
    for j in range(3):  # 3 keys in the data
          senddata.append([2, data[j]])
    recvdata = None
    if rank == 0:
            comm.Gatherv(senddata, recvdata, root=0)
```

And then scatter the dictionaries of the ones with highest values in key data['a'] into different processors.
I am not sure, how to "scatter" & if the code logic that I am using is correct or is there a simpler way.

Comment: Just a comment about the code that is "done". You are following the non-blocking sends and receives immediately by waits, which means that these calls are identical to the blocking versions. As a result, the code as written could deadlock if "send" is implemented synchronously (i.e. is not buffered) as MPI is allowed to do.You either need to post the receives before you wait on the sends, or use "sendrecv". As ever, the barrier is also not needed.

Comment: Thank you David, I tried the exact code given in the documentation (https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html). But yes, now I'm gonna make four "requests" and "wait" them all post all sends and receives. Any suggestion on how can I gather and scatter the dictionary. Do I need to define the datatype? Or can I simply write
**if rank == 0: 
data = comm.gather(data, root=0)**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution,

For sending and receiving:

```
            reqSend1 = self.comm.isend(data, dest=((self.size+self.rank+1)%self.size), tag=self.rank)
            reqRecv2 = self.comm.irecv(source=((self.size+self.rank-1)%self.size), tag=self.rank-1)
            dataPrev = reqRecv2.wait()
            reqSend1.wait()
```

And for Gather and scatter for python dictionaries, code logic is as follows:
Gather function:

```
if rank == 0:
        comm.Gather(data, root=0)
```

Scatter function:

```
if rank == 0:
        comm.Scatter(data, root=0)
```